# flask how to allow read/write file access

Tags: apache, flask, openldap

I am using Flask + Apache + Ubuntu20.04 + Pytho3-ldap3 and OpenLDAP as backend.

Now I need to provide a page that allow an administrator to change a file (read, insert or delete the content of file).

It is not an upload/download file.

Example: Administrator accesses https://flask/hosts and he can insert or delete the content of `/etc/hosts` file.

I think that I must use as example:

```
@app.route('/hosts')
def host():
with open ( '/etc/hosts' , 'w') as file:
```

In Apache I have: /etc/apache2/conf-files/hosts.conf

```
<File /etc/hosts>
        Require all granted 
</File>
```

But there is a lot missing... 8)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this is **really dangerous**.

You should not let people modify files on your server. It's a high-security risk.

*It looks like you do not have an app server. Flask is not your production server. You should use something compatible with WSGI like Gunicorn, uWSGI, Nginx Unit...*

Something more secure could be to handle every case, like:

```
@app.route("/add_entry", methods=["PUT"]):
def add_entry_to_host_file():
    entry = request.args.get("entry", type=str, default="")
    if check_entry(entry):
         add_entry_to_host_file(entry)
    return "something"
```

You'll see that this is really long and not really made for. Maybe you should use a different tool (configuration management tool) to do that like Ansible, Salt, Chef... They are more secure and made for that. You can probably find on Github a web interface for one of them if you want a user-friendly web interface.

*I know I did not really answer the question the way you expected the response but it's a real security risk.*

Comment: Thanks Victor. I used /etc/hosts as an example. I am developing a flask to interact with squid files. All flask apps are inside firewall rules . No security problem and only administrator can acess app with login/password. I see a lot of examples of upload and donwload, but almost none with flask modifing content of a file..8(